# Is it possible to "Like" a "fan page" using the Facebook SDK?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-like

I am trying to let users "like" a Facebook fan page from within an Android app.  I am able to successfully "like" objects such as wall comments using code like this,

```
mFacebook = new Facebook(APP_ID);   
SessionStore.restore(mFacebook, this);        

mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(mFacebook);
Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
mAsyncRunner.request(COMMENT_ID + "/likes", parameters, "POST", new MyRequestListener(), "");
```

However, if I put in a page id rather than a comment id, I get this error message in the Facebook response,

```
Response: {"error":{"type":"OAuthException","message":"(#200) App does not have permission to make this call"}}
```

I am obtaining both the "publish_stream" and "offline_access" publishing permissions at login, and they are given to the Facebook object with SessionStore.restore().

1) Does Facebook let apps "like" fan pages?

2) If so, any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Thanks,
Matt

Comment: You have the two stream permissions that are required. Is the fan page publicly available? I have similar logic in Python that works just fine for liking pages, unless the page is not public, in which case I get a permission error.

Comment: That's a good thought.  Yes, the Facebook page is public.  And it is helpful to know "liking" a page is possible from a third-party application.  I think the question now is whether there is a limitation in the Facebook Android SDK, or whether I am simply coding improperly.  You don't happen to be using Python within an Android app?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Facebook documentation for Pages has been updated and is current (see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/). You cannot like a Page via the Graph API, even though you can read the like count information.

Answer (score 7):

As other answers say, it is not possible to 'like' pages via the Graph API.

The confusion in this topic comes from the API documentation, where is says [You can comment on or like any object that has a /comments or /likes **connection**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) (The key term here is *connection*)

Going a little deeper: 
Any object (in this case a [Page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/)), has a number of Fields and Connections. Fields are basically used to access the object information and Connections are used to perform operations in that object.

In sum, a Page doesn't have a /likes Connection, but it has a /likes Field, reason why we can get the number of likes of a given page, but we cannot like a page.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, as far as I know so far, you can't like Pages via the API. You can render a Like button via a web view, but I think you're out of luck here at least.  You can (as you note) like comments and posts, but pages still require direct user interaction.

Comment: DoryEx, have you seen this formally documented somewhere?  I think you are likely right, but I have not seen this stated or implied anywhere in the Facebook Graph API documentation.  In fact the documenation seems to imply you should be able to like a page.  ["Like the given object if it has a /likes connection"](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) I am hesitant to accept this as the final answer yet.  I am curious if anyone knows if it is possible to like a page from an iPhone app.

Comment: Unfortunately no, I haven't seen it properly described - this is just from a lot of hunting and testing.  Hope it helps!

Comment: you can try this 
https://github.com/crowjdh/android-facebook-like-button-integration