# How to like Facebook status from app?

Tags: android, facebook

I am building a Facebook app in which I want to use the "like" functionality. When the user clicks on the Like button of a status then it should be updated in the Facebook database. Is there any URL or is there any method in the Facebook SDK to do it, and for comments as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got the answer here [Android How to like a post with facebook 3.0 sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14147877/android-how-to-like-a-post-with-facebook-3-0-sdk) , the second one....

```
Request likeRequest = new Request(Session.getActiveSession(), fBPostId + "/likes", null, HttpMethod.POST, new Request.Callback() {

         @Override
         public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                Log.i(TAG, response.toString());
         }
});
Request.executeBatchAndWait(likeRequest);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can create a `like` on a [Post](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/) by making a HTTP POST request to

```
POST_ID/likes
```

with the `publish_stream` [extended permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/extended-permissions/). If the write is successful, then it will return `true`.

Comment: i am new to android development, can you explain in detail??

Comment: Sorry, I don't have experience in android. But as far as documentation says, you might have to use [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.0/Request) and create HTTP `POST` method to `POST_ID/likes` graphPath and passing along `session`.