# Can we use Facebook PHP SDK to make current user like a facebook page

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I want to develop a Facebook Canvas that allow user to play the contest when they like my Facebook page.

In normal process, when user click accept button mean that they grant authentication to access their information as we set in authentication such as email, user_likes, publish_actions and so on.

after authenticated, Can we use PHP Facebook SDK like a Facebook page?

Comment: Why not just put a normal like button on the app and not enable any functionality until the user has liked the page? Though in my opinion the whole idea is pretty user-hostile.

Comment: @Chandara, only if you have users permission. Do you have it?

Comment: @Iguananaut, there are several reasons not to use normal like button. Especially when you want do more than just like.

Comment: @Jurik, i have permission "email, user_likes, publish_actions" and try to use this code $facebook->api("/app_ID/likes", "post", 
         array("access_token" => $access_token)
        ); but it still not work

Comment: I'm a bit confused the title is completely different from the content as well the first paragraph from the 2nd paragraph, can you specify what do you so I can help

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but you want to try `$facebook->api("/PAGE_ID/likes", "post", array("access_token" => $access_token) );` not app_id?
EDIT:
apparently it isn't possible (anymore?) to like fan pages via app. [Is it possible to "Like" a "fan page" using the Facebook SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5285574/is-it-possible-to-like-a-fan-page-using-the-facebook-sdk)

Comment: we can't do that, apparently. I got an error when I tested the action. Can't like fan pages via app, sorry. Eidted the answer.